# Is it possible to create a dictionary in PostgreSQL dynamically?

Tags: postgresql, dictionary, full-text-search, stop-words

I'm new to full text search in PostgreSQL and discovered things like Dictionaries and stop words in it.

I have a table with a lot of words from many texts. I want to create my own dictionary and put the first 30 most frequent words as stop words.

Is it possible to do this at runtime?

Comment: What is your schema?  What kind of data is stored in your table(s)?

Comment: @cdhowie Stop words are words like "the", "of", "in", etc. The schema is simple, a table which each row is a word and a dictionary is not a thing I want to invent, is a thing that PostgreSQL has support, but I didn't find if is possible create my own at runtime with the data I want.

Comment: If search is what you are after then you should probably leave the data as is and look into implementing a search specific solution like elasticsearch (http://www.elasticsearch.org/ ). This way you will get out of the box all the power of a search engine and you will also leave the database to handle just data input/output.

Answer (score 1):

Anything is possible.  Not everything is feasible.

What you can do without too much difficulty is create a stored procedure in a language like pl/perlU which breaks up the words, analyzes them, and writes stop words to a file.  You'd have to do a `pg_ctl reload` in order to ensure that the new stop words file was used.  However I don't think you can dynamically determine stop words at search time because if you search through the strings to look for stop words, there isn't much point in then having full text searching.

The actual stop words file is just a new-line separated list of words.  Also I think you'd need to start with a template for stemming purposes.  Trying to dynamically discover stemming would be both difficult and error-prone.